# Renaming multiple files with different names

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I am a programmer by no means and am brand new to using powershell, but have been tasked with setting up some batch export processes for daily files we FTP. I need to come up with a script that will take changing file names and change them within the same directory to new names;

Example: files will come in as below (YYYYMMDD will be the changing variable)

```
YYYYMMDD_Share_Support.txt
YYYYMMDD_Person_Support.txt
```

We need them to be stripped from the above to:

```
Share.txt
Person.txt
```

so on and so forth.

I have found ways to make this work, but only on an as needed basis for one file at a time with specific names, not names that will change daily.

So far I am using:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt

Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("NEWFILENAME.txt" -f $nr++)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the regex `-replace` operator inside a pipeline-bound scriptblock:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -filter *.txt 
$files |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^\d{8}_(.*)_Support\.txt$', '$1.txt' }
```

As [suggested by TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939007/renaming-multiple-files-with-different-names/58939283#comment104137052_58939283), if you know the relative position of the word you need, you can also use `-split`:

```
$files |Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}.txt' -f ($_.Name -split '_')[-2]}  # grab 2nd last word
```

Comment: An alternative: `-split '_')[1]`

Comment: Thanks so much Mathias, this appears to work perfectly for renaming the files I needed!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
dir *.txt | 
  rename-item -newname { $null,$base,$null = $_.basename -split '_'; "$base.txt" } -whatif
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a longer version of the answer. An alternative mentioned by @TheIncorrigible1

```
$logDir = "D:\Satish\TestFolders"
cd $logDir

$files = ls

foreach ($file in $files){
$fileSplit=($file.ToString()).split("_")


ren $file "$($fileSplit[1]).txt"

}
```

> And for Share.txt to YYYYMMDD_Share_Support.txt

```
$logDir = "D:\Satish\TestFolders"
cd $logDir

$files = ls

$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"

foreach ($file in $files){
$fileSplit=($file.ToString()).split(".")


ren $file "$($date)_$($fileSplit[0])_Support.txt"

}
```